# Associação de um ClientDataSet e um TZQuery (ZeosLib)

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma dúvida quanto a associação de um `ClientDataSet` e um `TZQuery`. Queria associar a mesma tabela que selecionei em meu `TZQuery`, com o meu `ClientDataSet`, pois quero gerar um arquivo <kbd>.XML</kbd>, a partir da tabela que  o meu `ClientDataSet` pegou.

A princípio, pensei que era assim:

```
ClientDataSet1.Assign(ZQuery1);
```

ou

```
ClientDataSet1.Data := ZQuery1
```

**Da um erro de tipos diferentes.**

Mas obviamente eu estava errado.

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer a ligação com `DataSetProvider` e abrir o `ClientDataSet` em vez da `ZQuery`.

Exemplo:

```delphi
procedure TMainForm.ObterDados;       
begin
  DataSetProvider.DataSet := ZQuery1;
  ClientDataSet1.SetProvider(DataSetProvider1);
  ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;
```

O DataSetProvider se encontra na paleta `Data Access`, a mesma do `ClientDataSet`.

Comment: Ele conseguiu pegar um registro apenas, o que poderia ser?

Answer (score 3):

```delphi
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tabc460 LIMIT 0, '+IntToStr(treg));
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Open;
DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.Open;
```

Ele funcionou com a query exata, ele listou todos os dados no meu arquivo .xml.

Comment: @TremDoido, verdade, estaria abrindo a mesma query 2 vezes. :S